# Python re module returning blank entries while using findall

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a python program to parse a log file and grab `.js` files' names from it. The script seems to identify blanks as well as the files. Not sure why...

```
import re

_logf = open('access_log.txt')
_list = []
_uniq = []

for line in _logf:        
    _list.append(re.findall(r'[^/]*\.js',line))

for item in _list:
    if item not in _uniq:
        _uniq.append(item)

print(sorted(_uniq))
```

The outputted list contains an empty list as follows. I tried to add `+` to the regex instead of `*`, but the output is still the same.

```
[[], ['jquery.js'], ['jquery.jshowoff.min.js'], ['jquery.jshowoff2.js']]
```

Comment: A **small** example of your log file will be helpful. See [mre] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You search the text document line by line, so it may happen that no match is found and the method `findAll()` also returns no matches and then an empty list `[]`.Try to read the document completely or filter out empty list elements using another loop or list comprehension.

See the documentation for more information about re.findAll():
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

You're appending to `_line` regardless of a hit being made or not. Only append to `_list` if you get a hit:

```
found = re.findall(r'[^/]*\.js',line)

if found:
    _list.append(found)
```

Also, the second part about uniqueness can probably be implemented as a set:

```
unique = set(_list)
```

.. your current implementation searches the whole list (or at least until a hit is made) for each insert, which is highly inefficient as the number of entries start to rise.

You can also implement it by only using the file name itself as the key in a dictionary, then calling `name_of_dict.keys()` to only get the keys (which will be unique). A dict is a hash table, meaning that inserts are O(1) for most cases - i.e. constant, instead of depending on the size of the dictionary (which `in` would do for a list).